# Why is my websites navigation bar overlapping content on the mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure what code is causing the problem, so I'm not sure what to post.

On my website the navigation bar is overlapping the content on the mobile version

The website is [www.seshilton.co.za](http://www.seshilton.co.za)

Comment: Please may you edit the question and include a [mcve] of the issue? It's not fair to ask others to debug your website for you

Comment: `header.masthead` should always have `padding-top: 17rem`

Comment: I will provide the example
I'm just not sure which snippet I should provide as I'm not sure what's causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a part in your code that goes something like this:

```
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

When I remove the `position: fixed;`, the image jumps down in mobile view under your navigation bar.

w3schools says the following:

> "An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
> viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
> page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
> to position the element.
>
> A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would
> normally have been located."

Try to work around that fixed value. Maybe use `position: sticky` instead with the combination of z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving margin-top for the header element for smaller screen sizes as,

```
@media(max-width:500px){
    header{
      margin-top:100px;
    }
```

something like this would workout, Trying changing the values of max-width and margin-top as per your need.